# Menucool Responsive Tabs hack

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, navigation

I used menucool's latest version of responsive tabs. When I'm developing my page locally, it seemed to work fine but when I actually make it live. The problem occur. The text "Trial Tabs Version" is showing as my first tab in the list of tabs I have even I have set an existing "First" tab. I have check the responsive-tab.js and its corresponding css but I cannot find the text. Has anyone used this before and came to found a solution for "hacking" or overriding this "unlicense" version ?

Thanks in advance!

cheers!